# Double controller call

Tags: angularjs

I have controller

```
sampleApp.controller('AddOrderController', function($scope) {
    console.log('Call AddOrderController');
    $scope.message = 'This is Add new order screen';

});
```

when I click on "Show Order" in Chromium console apper "Call ShowOrdersController" (All as I expect). 
Now when I click on "Add New Order " or "Show Order"  in console "Call AddOrderController" twice.

[Plinkr Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/85INOW?p=preview)

[image]

Why is controller called twice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example uses an old version of angular: **1.0.7**

This was probably a bug, anyway it was fixed with **angular 1.1.5**:

A plunker with 1.1.5: http://plnkr.co/edit/YJrpxQ?p=preview

A plunker with 1.2.10: http://plnkr.co/edit/hJ6qug?p=preview